# To convert a table into a specific format in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have a table with 1.7 million rows.
The table structure is (Datapoint,AttributeName,AttributeValue).

```
First column i.e Datapoint is like :
(1,AttributeName1,Attributevalue1)
(1,AttributeName2.Attributevalue2)
.
.
n times
(2,AttributeName1,Attributevalue1)
(2,AttributeName2,Attributevalue2)
.
.
m times
(11113,AttributeName1,Attributevalue1)
(11113,AttributeName2,Attributevalue2)
.
.
ptimes
```

I need to write a procedure in SQL which converts the above data into below format :

```
(Datapoint,AttributeName1,AttributeName2,.............AttributeNamen)
(1,       ,AttributeValue1,AttributeValue2,.........................)
(2,       ,AttributeValue1,AttributeValue2,.........................)

(11113,   ,AttributeValue1,AttributeValue2,.........................)
```

Please let me know how to go about it.
Thanks

Comment: Please mention what you have tried.

Comment: Search for "mysql pivot" or "mysql rows to columns"

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have a *pivot* function but you can transform the data from rows into columns using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select datapoint,
  max(case when AttributeName ='AttributeName1' then AttributeValue end) as AttributeName1,
  max(case when AttributeName ='AttributeName2' then AttributeValue end) as AttributeName2,
  max(case when AttributeName ='AttributeName3' then AttributeValue end) as AttributeName3,
  max(case when AttributeName ='AttributeName4' then AttributeValue end) as AttributeName4
from yourtable
group by datapoint
```

The above version will work great if you have a known number of values. But if you have an unknown number of items to transform into columns, then you will need to use a prepared statement to generate dynamic SQL.  You should review the following article:

[Dynamic pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html)

The code would be similar to this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(CASE WHEN AttributeName = ''',
      AttributeName,
      ''' THEN AttributeValue END) AS `',
      AttributeName, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM yourtable;


SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT datapoint, ', @sql, ' 
           from yourtable
           group by datapoint');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: I need to generalize like you have done in your 2nd method.But i'm not clear with the code , can you tell me from where i can read more about the above so that i understand what is going on?

Comment: @SahilMadan I edited my answer with a link to an article, but here is the link -- http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I understood how it's working..The procedure is executing without any error.But there is some Syntax error in "PREPARE stmt FROM @sql"..Don't know what is it..Any idea about this?

Comment: @SahilMadan What is the error message?

Comment: This is the error "PREPARE stmt FROM @sql Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT Datapoint, SELECT Datapoint, max(CASE WHEN AttributeName = '12' THEN Attr' at line 1 0.000 sec"

Comment: @SahilMadan My guess is that the string you are creating to too long.  The `GROUP_CONCAT` has a default length of 1024, so you will have to alter the value. Prior to running the query, you will want to run `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = val;` Change the `val` to the length that you want.

Comment: I changed the val according to what you said, But the query is executing for the last 1 hour or so.I guess it's because of the large number of rows (1.7 million) and 3000+ attributes.

Comment: @SahilMadan If you have 3000+ attributes to transform then this is going to take a long time to process.  I would not recommend transforming data into 3000+ columns.